# Insert div into a menu item before the link and more

Tags: wordpress, menu, menuitem, wp-nav-walker

I already asked this on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ but nobody replied. There are similar questions but I think they are intended for theme developers and not for someone who is simply using some theme and wants to extend a bit its functionality.

I make a web page in Wordpress using a certain theme. Now, this theme has an expected markup for the menus:

```
<ul id=”primary-navigation-main”>
    <li>
        <a href=”https://example.com/page1”>Page 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href=”https://example.com/page1”>Page 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href=”https://example.com/page1”>Page 3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

On the mobile menu the wishes are slightly different. In the company they want some transition while pressing on the menu item. Something that I solved at another (hardcoded) menu like that:

```
<ul id=”primary-navigation-main”>
    <li>
        <div class=”transition-div”></div>
        <a href=”https://example.com/page1”>
            <p>Page 1</p>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class=”transition-div”></div>
        <a href=”https://example.com/page1”>
            <p>Page 2</p>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class=”transition-div”></div>
        <a href=”https://example.com/page1”>
            <p>Page 3</p>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

or like in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/igorbeuermann/8wraLv37/1/).

I don’t know if this is the best solution for this transition but it works.

So, I would like to add `<div>` into `<li>` before `<a>` and in the `<a>` I would like to add `<p>`. I was fiddling `with wp_nav_menu` and `wp_nav_menu_items` but I wasn’t successful. Do I need to register `<ul>` or something else? Also it seems I will have to use a Walker class but I don't know how.

Now, beacuse I didn't get any response I already found a [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/igorbeuermann/6Lwpeqvd/53/) for the original theme's markup (without `div` and `p`). But still the question remains: how to insert an arbitrary markup into a certain existing menu (in my case the primary menu of the chosen theme). That is into each menu item `li` and then into each link `a`, preserving the menu's URLs.

Could anybody help me or simply tell me it's not possible? I could already used `wp_nav_menu_items` for inserting an item to the menu. Therefore I thought `wp_nav_menu` offers functionality for a bit more detailed work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below code in your function file

```
class AWP_Menu_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth=0, $args=[], $id=0) {
        $output .= "<li class='" .  implode(" ", $item->classes) . "'>";
 
        $output .= '<div class="transition-div"></div>'; //Put your content here
        
        if ($item->url && $item->url != '#') {
            $output .= '<a href="' . $item->url . '">';
        } else {
            $output .= '<span>';
        }
 
        $output .= $item->title;
 
        if ($item->url && $item->url != '#') {
            $output .= '</a>';
        } else {
            $output .= '</span>';
        }
 
        if ($args->walker->has_children) {
            $output .= '<i class="caret fa fa-angle-down"></i>';
        }
    }
}
```

Add walker where you get menu in template (or header)

```
wp_nav_menu([
    ...
    ...
    'walker' => new AWP_Menu_Walker()
]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @VickyP for your answer! I only saw it now so I am late for reply.
I understand a bit more how to insert things into a link.

I found a place in a theme where I should put the walker in the wp_nav_menu() but there already exists the theme walker. These lines in the wp_nav_menu() in the original file: 
'walker'         => '\Neve\Views\Nav_Walker',
'fallback_cb'    => '\Neve\Views\Nav_Walker::fallback',
I replaced the existing walker with your one and got an error. Probably I should register the walker somewhere. When I'll get the solution, I'll accept your the answer.

Comment: Now, I got it. It shows a menu with the markup I want. But I get a new menu beside the existing one. I suppose, I didn't target the right space. Nevertheless, I know now how to add markup into the menu item. The question is therefore answered and I will accept the answer. If you can help me with the targeting the right space in Neve theme I would  appreciate. But I'll go to the Neve forum too.

Thanks again, @VickiP!

Comment: @IgorBeuermann you can try to modify Neve theme walker with above walker. It placed at  inc/views/nav_walker.php

Comment: Nice tip, @VickyP !
Or, perhaps because it is just a class extending Walker_Nav_Menu, I could just add it in the same file. I don't know, how it works. Worth trying :)

Comment: @IgorBeuermann, you should add this code in seperate file and include this file in function.php file for WordPress standard.